# Что делать после написание рабочего проекта в visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

я написал мини программу(куб который вращается помощью opengl).
что надо сделать что бы запустить этот проект без visual studio на другом компе?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно создать инсталляционный пакет. 
Существует множество способов, как по мне то лучшый вариант это [WIX TOOLSET](http://wixtoolset.org/)

[Создание инсталлятора с помощью WiX](https://habrahabr.ru/post/68616/)

Answer (score 1):

В папке ваш_проект/bin/Debug (или Release) появился .exe файл. Его можно безболезненно запускать на любом операционно- (виндовс) и архитектурно- (любой ПК х86 и\или х64 в зависимости от настроек проекта) совместимом оборудовании + на нем должна быть установлена совместимая версия .Net Framework.

Comment: А зачем .NET? ТС вроде же компилирует проект на C++?